# I am trying to fetch top rated 3 products

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
// @route   GET /api/products/top
// @desc    Get top rated products
// @access  Public
router.get(
  '/top',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({}).sort({ rating: -1 }).limit(3)

    res.json(products)
  })
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7sjI.png)

Cast to ObjectId failed for value "top" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhMV3.png)

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the route you have shown here is not colliding with any other routes that accept path parameters. Maybe check for a route that looks like this:

```
/api/products/:id
```

If there's any route under products that looks like this, try to add some logs to it and see if they are shown, this means that you were calling a different API all along.

It might be that the word "top" is being considered as an Object ID, hence the error you are getting.

If that was the case, I would suggest renaming either of the APIs to avoid such conflict.

Comment: // This is the route which is defined in server.js
app.use('/api/products', require('./routes/productRoute'))

Comment: Can you add a picture of the product route file that includes all product routes?

Comment: https://ideone.com/eb0tZI

Comment: please checkout from here

Comment: @Usamakhan so on line 36 you have declared a GET api that accepts and id as a path parameter. But you also have the /top api which is also a GET api. These two apis are colliding with each other. You could try to change the route or the method of either APIs to fix this. If this works please mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: To break it down, you have two apis that share the same method and one of them accepts an id as path parameter to get a product by its Id. What happens is when you tried to call the /top API, the API on line 36 was triggered and the string “top” was passed as the ID. Since it is a 3 character string it cannot be cast into an Object ID. Hence the error you saw.